# Sending email using DelayedJob gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

There is the following code for sending email asynchronously:

```
class OrderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "some mail"

  def send_order_info(order) 
    @order = order
    mail(to: Settings.report_email, subject: "Some subject")
  end

  #handle_asynchronously :send_order_info
end
```

It code works, but if I remove comment from 'handle_asynchronously' line I can't send any email. What is the trouble? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you run DJ worker?

Comment: Run `bundle exec rake jobs:work`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Why do you want to comment out your `handle_asynchronously` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send email in background then do

```
 OrderMailer.delay.send_order_info(@order)
```